# Make each div fade in after 0.2 seconds sequentially, not ascynchronously

Tags: jquery, css, each, transition

I have the following function which makes every div inside `#pic-grid` fade and zoom in.

I want each div to fade in in sequence, but slightly overlapping. The transition of each fade-in is `0.2` so I want the first div to fade in at `0.1` (already set in code by the `setTimeout` for 100) and then the second div should start loading in after only `0.1s` (100 milliseconds).

I have tried adding `setTimeout` to the `.each()` function but it doesn't seem to transition at all.

```
function fadeInImages(parentDiv){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(parentDiv).children('div').each(function () {
                        console.log(this);
                        $(this).css('opacity','1').css('transform','scale(1)');
                });
            }, 100);
        }
```

## Codepen: http://codepen.io/franhaselden/pen/RWyxqJ

Comment: I would use css animations with a delay for each div. No js needed.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19478294/how-create-a-chained-delayed-animation-sequence-in-jquery Should be able to use fadeIn instead of animate.

Comment: This function is part of a larger piece of code that uses jQuery, so I'd like to keep it within jQuery as more will come later.

Comment: check this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyZzGq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my code, simple, no timeouts, no delays:
DEMO http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaGQvm

```
var i = 0;
var length = $('#pic-grid').children('div').length;
doAnimate(i, length);
function doAnimate(i, length){
  if(i < length){
     $($('#pic-grid').children('div')[i]).animate({"opacity": 1}, 100, function(){doAnimate(i + 1, length);});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

JS:

```
var animate = function(fadeIn, time, offset) {

  $(fadeIn).each(function() {
    var me = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
      me.css({
        'opacity': 1,
        'transform': 'scale(1)'
      });
    }, time)
    time = time + offset;
  });
}

animate('#pic-grid > div', 0, 500);
```

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avGExw)

Answer (score 0):

This code is based primarily on your codepen, with some minor tweaks:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  // We need to store the time delay so we can increment it
  var t = 0;
  $('#pic-grid').children('div').each(function() {
    // setTimeout looses the "this" scope, so set a variable here to use in setTimeout
    var _this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
      _this.css('opacity', '1').css('transform', 'scale(1)')
    }, (++t * 200));
  });
}, 100);
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyZzdd

Answer (score 0):

use below code

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyZzGq)

```
var i = 0;
var divLength = $('#pic-grid').children('div').length;
var interval = setInterval(function() {

  $('#pic-grid').children('div:eq('+i+')').css('opacity', '1').css('transform', 'scale(1)')
  if(divLength == (i + 1)){
    clearInterval(interval)
  }
  i++;

}, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWyxmY

```
$('#pic-grid').children('div').hide();
setTimeout(function() {
  var timeSpanMS = 200;
  $('#pic-grid').children('div').each(function(i) {
    console.log(this);
    $(this).delay( i*(timeSpanMS/2) ).fadeIn(timeSpanMS);    
  });
}, 100);
```